Differentiate $\int_1^x\frac{1}{t}dt$ for $0<x<1$
We know that by the fundamental theorem of calculus (FTC), for $x\geq 1$, we have $$\frac{d}{dx}\int_1^x\frac{1}{t}dt=\frac{1}{x}.$$ Do we have the same result when $0<x<1$? Most of the resources online about FTC only covers $x\geq 1$. Thank you for your help.

$\frac{d}{dx}\int_{a}^{f(x)}g(t)dt=g(f(x))f'(x),$ where $g(a)$ is well-defined.
This is always true. Actually, for your question, you can compute $$\int_{1}^{x}\frac{1}{t}dt=\ln x  \; \text{ if } \; x>0,  $$
$$\frac{d}{dx}\ln x=\frac{1}{x}\;\text{ when } \; x \in (0,1) .$$

Thank you for your help

@KHOOS You are welcome!
